# How to send the values using different button in same activity?

Tags: android, json, android-button

I'm using json parsing in my application first one has following http://shdg.com/webservice/interestreceiveddetail?version=apps&received_detail_id=2783&user_login_id=2650
Here I've so many fields from which I need to use two fields when user click on button
first one is user_status and another one is interest_id.
To send this request I've this URL 
http:/fjshdjhs.com/webservice/interestreceivedprocess?version=apps&user_status=N&interest_id=1288

Now i need to send N with user_status,so how to do this..[image]

Comment: which button ? question is not clear.

Comment: there are two image icons at bottom with right and cross sign,here right means request accepted and cross means decline

Comment: Hey try to given ans to your question with second account @Eddie as your all previous question so have you think we all are stupid here to help you ?.

Comment: @Johnson did u try to add click listener to your button ? Also please accept answers. Even if it is your friend, ask him to accept answer, else no one will take interest in answering your question.

Comment: @HareshChhelana its nothing like that that id is used by my friend,just cool brother

Comment: @AndroidKiller i wish i can post code but its not allowing

Comment: @Johnson,Really so you both are asking same question is it ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana he is helping me in my project so some times he asks,just relax and happy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
        String endPoint="http://gujjumatch.com/webservice/interestreceivedprocess?";
        String url;
        try {
            JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(response);
            String user_status=resultObject.getString("user_status");
            int interest_id=resultObject.getInt("interest_id");
            if (user_status.equals("Decline")){
                user_status="N";
            }
            String params="version=apps"
                    +"&user_status="+user_status
                    +"&interest_id="+interest_id;
            url=endPoint+params;
            Log.v("URL",url);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: send out or post it here.

Comment: Brother i tried with your idea its working thank you,i just need to pass status only and i was calling wrong value..i accept and vote up.